# Xamarin Android: Why overriden OnSaveInstanceState never gets called?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm trying to persist some data when device orientation changes in order to not requery an SQLite table again. Here's my code:

```
 SfDataGrid grid;
 string jsonData;

protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
    SetContentView(Resource.Layout.CaseControl);
    RelativeLayout layout = FindViewById<RelativeLayout>(Resource.Id.layoutCasos);

    grid = new SfDataGrid(this);

    grid.AllowResizingColumn = true;
    grid.AllowSorting = true;

    layout.AddView(grid);

    if (savedInstanceState != null)
    {
       string savedJsonData = savedInstanceState.GetString("jsonData");
       grid.ItemsSource = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TableQuery<v_Casos>>(savedJsonData);

    }

    else
    {
        string dpPath = Path.Combine("/data/data/TPProject.TPProject/files/", "PranfHurto.db3");
        var db = new SQLiteConnection(dpPath);
        var data = db.Table<v_Casos>();
        grid.ItemsSource = data;

        jsonData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
    }

    grid.SelectionMode = SelectionMode.Single;
    grid.GridLongPressed += RowLongPress;

}

protected override void OnSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)
{
    outState.PutString("jsonData", jsonData);

    base.OnSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
```

As you see, I put the jsonData inside the outState. However it always comes back null after the device orientation changes. I put a breakpoint inside that method but it never gets fired. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Could you please show your ActivityAttribute?  Was the `OnDestory()` method called when you rotate the screen?

Comment: Joe, you mean this?  [Activity(Label = "Casos AAA")] ... that's the only attribute above the activity. How can I know if OnDestroy() is called when I rotate the screen? I need to override it also?

Comment: Ok, I just want check if the activity execute the `onDestory()` and  recreate when you rotate the screen,  if it recreate, so the `OnSaveInstanceState` will be called. If you just copy and paste solve it, maybe it will recover, or there is no problem in your code. Good 
 luck.

Answer (score 0):

The weird solution for me was, instead of writing the overriden method, copy and pasting it. Then clean and build solution and now it works.